# Correct Circuit Sizing - Two Machines Woodworking Shop

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, woodworking

I have two machines that require 220+ and I was wondering if one double pole 230 amp breaker would do the trick for both?  The run is approximately 60' so I'm wondering if 12 awg wire will work or if I should go for 10?

It'd be great to get a pointer on how to do this math myself too :)

I am running a dust collector and a table saw so they will definitely be running at the same time.

Photos of motors and plugs below:
[image: dust collector motor]
[image: dust collector plug]
[image: table saw motor]
[image: table saw plug]

Comment: Pretty sure you didn't mean 230 amp breaker, but can't tell if you wanted to say 20 or 30?

Comment: The dust collector always gets 'ya. At least you're planning it in advance instead of as an afterthought.  @JPhi1618 "230” is a common model number for breakers which are 2 pole 30A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet here is to run two 20A circuits.  You might be able to run the saw and collector at the same time on one 20A circuit because they normally operate below their peak power, but you would trip breakers often when cutting through difficult wood.

Your saw requires 13 amps (rounding up) and has a 15 amp plug.  The collector needs 11 amps and has a 20 amp plug.  Not sure on the plug choices by the manufacturer, but that's what they did.  When they are both operating you could have up to 26 amps.  That won't trip a circuit breaker immediately, but it won't last very long like that.

You can't run a 30A circuit and put two 20A receptacles on it.  General purpose circuits are limited to 20 amps.  Since you have a long run, it might make more sense to run something like a 60A service to a sub-panel in your shop for future expansion.  There are several other questions here about sub-panels and their wiring.

Comment: Motors also pull alot of current on start up - I bet if the collector is already running, and you try to start the saw, it would definitely trip a single 20A.

And if you're going for a sub panel, you might as well go for at least 100A.  Headroom for more toys!

Comment: @CoAstroGeek, true on startup currents.  If it wasn't clear, I don't recommend trying a single 20A.  It _might_ work in _some_ cases, but you're not going to have a good time.

Answer (score 1):

To do both on 1 circuit you take 125% of the larger motor FLA and 100% of the remaining motor(s) or 26 amps so this would not work on a 20 amp circuit. You would need to run 30 amp with #10 but in my opinion 2ea 20 amp circuits would be safer.